# Compare Columns Date /w Todays Date

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to compare the column: `LastUpdated` with **todays** date in days, rounded to 1 decimal place. I keep getting the error

```
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00904: "DATEDIFF": invalid identifier
```

Any ideas?

```
SELECT
DISTINCT "AppName",
"ApprovedForRelease",
DATEDIFF(DAY,"LastUpdated",GETDATE())  AS "DaySinceUpdated" 
FROM BR_APP
WHERE "ApprovedForRelease" = 'Y';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle, you can use subtraction.  To get the dates between, truncate off the time:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "AppName", "ApprovedForRelease",
       (TRUNC(sysdate) - TRUNC("LastUpdated"))  AS "DaySinceUpdated" 
FROM BR_APP
WHERE "ApprovedForRelease" = 'Y';
```

The code you have used is based on SQL Server.